# SQL - joining on multiple columns in the same row

Tags: sql-server, join

Our school's ERP has a nasty database structure to it and since it is not normalized correctly, I have an issue with joining on the same table multiple times.

The DegreeHistory table has these columns in one row entry for a person:

```
|Major1|Major2|Major3|Minor1|Minor2|Minor3|
-------|------|------|------|------|------|
 CMPT                 BUSI
```

There is another table DegreeDescription:

```
|DegreeCode|DegreeDesc      |
-----------|-----------------
CMPT       |Computer Science
BUSI       |Business
```

I want a query shows a student's degree history information but skips the degree codes and shows the degree description instead.  Is there a way I can do this other than:

```
SELECT dd.DegreeDesc, dd1.DegreeDesc FROM DegreeHistory dh
LEFT JOIN DegreeDescription dd ON dd.DegreeCode = dh.Major1
LEFT JOIN DegreeDescription dd1 ON dd1.DegreeCode = dh.Major2 ...
```

For each of the possible majors, minors, concentrations, certifications, etc...  Seems like a large and ugly query (though simple to do).

Comment: It looks ridiculous, but yes, how you have it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right track, just a little change...:

```
SELECT dd.DegreeDesc, dd1.DegreeDesc FROM DegreeHistory dh
LEFT JOIN DegreeDescription ON DegreeCode = dh.Major1 dd
LEFT JOIN DegreeDescription ON DegreeCode = dh.Major2 dd1 ...
```

Certainly it's ugly but that's what you get with non-normalized structures :-(